# How did I make recursive copies of my repo inside of itself?

Tags: git, bash

I forgot what I typed exactly last night, but I remember typing a git command incorrectly and wondering if I messed something up. I figured everything was fine, made a commit then went to sleep.

Now today, when I `git status` I get 100+ lines of

```
new file: MyProject/MyProject/ 
new file: MyProject/MyProject/MyProject/ 
new file: MyProject/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject/
```

and so on. Every directory has a copy of all my code and resources, too. 
`git checkout -- .` did not fix this. I can rebase to a previous commit since I remember all the changes from my last commit, but I'd like to know how I caused such a mess.

What the hell did I do and how can I fix this and never do it again?

My commit:
    commit 82a828d4bcdb74248f2183e4092974399ecfb4d2
    Author: ----- ---
    Date:   Wed Aug 28 20:03:02 2013 -0400

```
    Added background(s) to table view


diff --git a/Spots.xcodeproj/.LSOverride b/Spots.xcodeproj/.LSOverride
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..5d27049
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots.xcodeproj/.LSOverride differ
diff --git a/Spots.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/Spots.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
index 4ccff74..164b0b2 100644
--- a/Spots.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
+++ b/Spots.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -11,6 +11,18 @@
                943BDCB217C96F8900923C1C /* SpotViewController.m in Sources */ =
                943BEE6017A5DBBB00E16CDE /* ECSlidingViewController.m in Sources
                943BEE6117A5DBBB00E16CDE /* UIImage+ImageWithUIView.m in Sources
+               944DDFC517CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern_@2X.png in Resources */
+               944DDFC617CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern.png in Resources */ = {
+               944DDFCD17CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood_@2X.png in Resources */ =
+               944DDFCE17CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood.png in Resources */ = {is
+               944DDFCF17CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood_@2X.png in Resources */ 
+               944DDFD017CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood.png in Resources */ = {i
+               944DDFD117CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1_@2X.png in Resources */ = {is
+               944DDFD217CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1.png in Resources */ = {isa = 
+               944DDFD717CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall_@2X.png in Resources *
+               944DDFD817CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall.png in Resources */ = 
+               944DDFD917CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy_@2X.png in Resources */ = {isa
+               944DDFDA17CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy.png in Resources */ = {isa = P
                94779A5717B43D5600D209A3 /* AddViewController.m in Sources */ = 
                94779A5E17B44DFC00D209A3 /* Notes.txt in Resources */ = {isa = P
                94B794CA17CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder.png in Resources */ = {i
@@ -64,11 +76,23 @@
                943BEE5D17A5DBBB00E16CDE /* ECSlidingViewController.m */ = {isa 
                943BEE5E17A5DBBB00E16CDE /* UIImage+ImageWithUIView.h */ = {isa 
                943BEE5F17A5DBBB00E16CDE /* UIImage+ImageWithUIView.m */ = {isa 
+               944DDFC317CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern_@2X.png */ = {isa = PBX
+               944DDFC417CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern.png */ = {isa = PBXFile
+               944DDFC717CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood_@2X.png */ = {isa = PBXFi
+               944DDFC817CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood.png */ = {isa = PBXFileRe
+               944DDFC917CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood_@2X.png */ = {isa = PBXF
+               944DDFCA17CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood.png */ = {isa = PBXFileR
+               944DDFCB17CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1_@2X.png */ = {isa = PBXFileRe
+               944DDFCC17CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1.png */ = {isa = PBXFileRefere
+               944DDFD317CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall_@2X.png */ = {isa = PB
+               944DDFD417CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall.png */ = {isa = PBXFil
+               944DDFD517CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy_@2X.png */ = {isa = PBXFileRef
+               944DDFD617CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy.png */ = {isa = PBXFileReferen
                94779A5517B43D5600D209A3 /* AddViewController.h */ = {isa = PBXF
                94779A5617B43D5600D209A3 /* AddViewController.m */ = {isa = PBXF
                94779A5D17B44DFC00D209A3 /* Notes.txt */ = {isa = PBXFileReferen
-               94B794C817CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder.png */ = {isa = PBXFileR
-               94B794C917CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder@2x.png */ = {isa = PBXFi
+               94B794C817CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder.png */ = {isa = PBXFileR
+               94B794C917CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder@2x.png */ = {isa = PBXFi
                94D27623179C790F0061E55E /* Spots.app */ = {isa = PBXFileReferen
                94D27626179C790F0061E55E /* UIKit.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileR
                94D27628179C790F0061E55E /* Foundation.framework */ = {isa = PBX
@@ -373,6 +397,18 @@
                D3BC34E617B993770026A32E /* Graphics */ = {
                        isa = PBXGroup;
                        children = (
+                               944DDFD317CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall_@2X.pn
+                               944DDFD417CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall.png */
+                               944DDFD517CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy_@2X.png */,
+                               944DDFD617CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy.png */,
+                               944DDFC717CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood_@2X.png *
+                               944DDFC817CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood.png */,
+                               944DDFC917CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood_@2X.png 
+                               944DDFCA17CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood.png */,
+                               944DDFCB17CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1_@2X.png */,
+                               944DDFCC17CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1.png */,
+                               944DDFC317CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern_@2X.png
+                               944DDFC417CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern.png */,
                                94B794C817CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder.png */,
                                94B794C917CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder@2x.png *
                                D3E43F1D17B9CEE400736C51 /* leftArrow.png */,
@@ -442,6 +478,18 @@
                                D3E43F2017B9CEE400736C51 /* leftArrow@2x.png in 
                                94B794CA17CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder.png in R
                                94B794CB17CC3FDE003CA531 /* placeholder@2x.png i
+                               944DDFC517CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern_@2X.png
+                               944DDFC617CEC0BF00F12B42 /* wood_pattern.png in 
+                               944DDFCD17CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood_@2X.png i
+                               944DDFCE17CEC53C00F12B42 /* purty_wood.png in Re
+                               944DDFCF17CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood_@2X.png 
+                               944DDFD017CEC53C00F12B42 /* retina_wood.png in R
+                               944DDFD117CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1_@2X.png in Re
+                               944DDFD217CEC53C00F12B42 /* wood_1.png in Resour
+                               944DDFD717CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall_@2X.pn
+                               944DDFD817CEC5F600F12B42 /* concrete_wall.png in
+                               944DDFD917CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy_@2X.png in Res
+                               944DDFDA17CEC5F600F12B42 /* noisy.png in Resourc
                        );
                        runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
                };
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall.png b/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..2de2c96
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a1241e1
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/concrete_wall_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/noisy.png b/Spots/Graphics/noisy.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..8aa2f7a
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/noisy.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/noisy_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/noisy_@2X.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0dbdcdd
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/noisy_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/placeholder.png b/Spots/Graphics/placeholder.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a081ba6
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/placeholder.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/placeholder@2x.png b/Spots/Graphics/placeholder@2x.p
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f4ffb48
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/placeholder@2x.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood.png b/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..37fcd07
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood_@2X.p
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..943c83c
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/purty_wood_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood.png b/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..22f2450
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood_@2X
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..83f2ceb
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/retina_wood_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/wood_1.png b/Spots/Graphics/wood_1.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d2e51e0
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/wood_1.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/wood_1_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/wood_1_@2X.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d1fa60d
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/wood_1_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern.png b/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern.png
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..fcc321d
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern_@2X.png b/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern_@
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..4c807e1
Binary files /dev/null and b/Spots/Graphics/wood_pattern_@2X.png differ
diff --git a/Spots/NearbyTableViewController.m b/Spots/NearbyTableViewController
index 7224b0c..e80eeb2 100644
--- a/Spots/NearbyTableViewController.m
+++ b/Spots/NearbyTableViewController.m
@@ -52,9 +52,12 @@ static NSString* const kBCURL = @"xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxx.xxx";
     self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

     self.tableView.rowHeight = 180.0;
-    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0
     self.tableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
-    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
+    
+    UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
+    patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage image
+    patternView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAuto
+    self.tableView.backgroundView = patternView;    

     if (!self.spotDictionary)
     {
diff --git a/Spots/placeholder.png b/Spots/placeholder.png
deleted file mode 100644
index a081ba6..0000000
Binary files a/Spots/placeholder.png and /dev/null differ
diff --git a/Spots/placeholder@2x.png b/Spots/placeholder@2x.png
deleted file mode 100644
index f4ffb48..0000000
Binary files a/Spots/placeholder@2x.png and /dev/null differ
```

seems pretty innocuous.

Comment: Does your shell have a history function so you can find out what you did?  Does your project have itself as a submodule?  Is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking though the history now. There's a `mv` command I could've screwed up, but it looks like it was done before I would've done this. Having myself as a submodule would make sense but... was I doing malicious git in my sleep?

Comment: Update: Rebased up one commit. Everything is back to normal, but I'm still very curious how that kind of mess could happen so subtly. If this went unnoticed for a while, it could've turned into a load of F'ing BS.

Comment: What was in that commit?

Comment: Perhaps you had created a symlink something like `MyProject -> .` that caused your filesystem hierarchy to appear infinitely recursive. That would be unrelated to Git, of course.

Comment: @CarlNorum - 10 or so png's for backgrounds to elements in my iOS application, and the lines of code to implement them where I want them. Nothing obscure.

Comment: Can you `git show` the commit and show the output here?

Comment: @GregHewgill very well possible, but I don't know the command to make symlinks from Terminal so it would have to have been some application trying to do me a favor. Also, I don't think it was infinite- just 100-200 copies (though some process could have imposed a cutoff)

Comment: @CarlNorum I rebased, then pulled, then committed anew, and pushed. I don't know if I can find that commit.

Comment: `git reflog` can help you track it down.

Comment: Posted the commit. Doesn't seem like there's anything that could've duplicated the directory. I'm starting to think git had nothing to do with this.

Comment: That seems most likely, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following steps:

- Go to `MyProject`.
- Create an empty file you'll find again, like `HelloWorld.txt`.
- Look into `MyProject/MyProject` and see if the file appears there.
- If the file appears there, you've somehow indeed created a symbolic link (make sure to remove the link, not the files "inside").
- If the file doesn't appear there, you've just created a copy for whatever reason.
- Move `MyProject/MyProject` outside, e.g. to `MyProject.bak`.
- Check `git status` to see whether you still see modified stuff (especially files deleted within `MyProject/MyProject`).
- If everything is fine, it should be save to delete `MyProject.bak`, but make sure you didn't save any changes to this rather than your original copy.
- If you now see the sub directories as modified you somehow added them to the repository as a sub module (although I wouldn't expect that; you most likely just screwed up some copying or checkout command?).